# java android HttpURLConnection how to get response 401

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I'm making an android app, which will connect to a web server using xauth authentication. My problem is that i can't get response if server returns 401 which causes java exception.

I need that response to know what am I doing wrong.

First of all, is HttpURLConnection good for this kind of stuff
Secondly, how can I get response anyway?

```
URL u_rl = new URL(url);
    final HttpURLConnection connection =
        (HttpURLConnection) u_rl.openConnection();

    connection.setRequestMethod(method);

    if (authorization != null) {
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
    }
    final byte[] body = parameters.getBytes();

        connection.setRequestProperty(
            "Content-Length", Integer.toString(body.length));
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();
        final OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
        output.write(body);
        output.flush();
        System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            result.put("error", connection.getResponseCode()+"");
            return null;
        }

        String out = IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream());
```

I know why I get 400 or other response code, the problem is that user don't know why. Server returns me an error in JSON and I'd like to get that JSON code even if response code isn't  200

Comment: You have to post a bit of code ?

Comment: If my below answer helps you please accept my answer and up vote me it will be much appreciated . Thanks :)

Comment: Posted code, but it doesn't have anything in common to my problem, i think?